# How to use Poco ProcessHandle with sed linux command that contains asterisk widlcard

Tags: c++, linux, sed, wildcard, poco-libraries

I want to create a c++ app for ubuntu 16.04  that retrieves data from folder /sys/class/net/eth0/statistics/. Specifically I need to get rx_bytes and rx_packets. The command that I have tried succesfully in terminal is the following:

```
sed -n -e 3p -e 13p /sys/class/net/enp0s3/statistics/*
```

I tried to give the same command using Poco ProcessHandle method using the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "Poco/Exception.h"
#include "Poco/Process.h"
#include "Poco/Pipe.h"
#include "Poco/PipeStream.h"

using namespace std;
using Poco::Process;
using Poco::ProcessHandle;
using Poco::Pipe;
using Poco::PipeInputStream;
using Poco::PipeOutputStream;
using Poco::Exception;

int main(int argc, char** argv)

{

    try {

        std::vector<std::string> args;

        std::string cmd = "sed";

        args.push_back("-n");
        args.push_back("-e");
        args.push_back("3p");
        args.push_back("-e");
        args.push_back("15p");
        args.push_back("/sys/class/net/enp0s3/statistics/*");

        Pipe outPipe;

        ProcessHandle ph = Process::launch(cmd, args, 0, &outPipe, 0);

        PipeInputStream istr(outPipe);

        std::string s;
        int c = istr.get();
        while (c != -1) {
            s += (char)c;
            c = istr.get();
        }
        std::cout << "string is " << s << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    catch (Poco::Exception& exc)

    {

        std::cerr << exc.displayText() << exc.code() << string(exc.name()) << std::endl;

        return 1;
    }
```

However I get the error message:

```
sed: can't read /sys/class/net/enp0s3/statistics/*: No such file or directory
```

When I try the code with a specific file I get the correct strings.
I know that there is the command cat alternative but is there any way for the above code to work succesfully.

Comment: I guess it may be a double quotes issue. `ls "/va*"` and `ls /va*` is different.

Comment: @Lee HoYo So you mean that I should insert the "/sys/class/net/enp0s3/statistics/*" into double quotes or something else ?

Comment: don't use double quotes if these is a wildcard `*`